# Filemaker: webviewer timer

Tags: javascript, timer, filemaker

I’m trying to make in FileMaker a web viewer to show some “countdown” for my medical office.

I’m trying to adapt this code I have found on internet:

```
     "data:text/html,<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

/*Setting JavaScript Variables to value of FileMaker fields*/
var targetTimeTxt = '" & Timer::Timestamp_End & "';
var status = '" & Timer::Status & "';
var labelTxt = '" & Timer::Label & "';
/*End FileMaker Fields*/

var currentTime = new Date();
var targetTime = new Date(targetTimeTxt);
var remaining = Math.floor((targetTime - currentTime)/1000);

function setClock()
{
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    var labelobj = document.getElementById('label1');
    var secondsRemaining=0;
    if(labelTxt=='')
    {
        labelobj.innerHTML='Timer';
    }
    else
    {
        labelobj.innerHTML=labelTxt;
    }

    if (targetTime>currentTime)
    {
        secondsRemaining=Math.floor((targetTime - currentTime)/1000);
    }

    var hours = Math.floor( secondsRemaining / 3600 );
    var minutes = Math.floor((secondsRemaining%3600) / 60 );
    if(minutes<10)minutes='0' + minutes;
    var seconds = secondsRemaining%60;
    if(seconds<10)seconds='0'+seconds;

    clock.innerHTML=hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    if(targetTimeTxt=='' || status=='Acknowledged' || ( secondsRemaining==0 && Math.floor(currentTime/1000)%2==0 ) )
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';
        if ( targetTimeTxt=='' || status=='Acknowledged' )
        {
            clock.innerHTML='--:--:--';
        }
    }
    else if(secondsRemaining==0)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF00';
        document.getElementById('sound1').Play();
    }

    setTimeout('setClock();',1000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body style='margin:4px;padding:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;' onload='setClock();'>
<div id='label1' style='font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;'>
</div>
<div id='clock'>
</div>
<embed src='file:///System/Library/Sounds/Glass.aiff' autostart='false'  id='sound1'
enablejavascript='true' width='0' height='0'>
</body></html>"
```

The FileMaker Var are correct, and the time stamp end car get  dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss results.

The web viewer works, but the timer starts always with a 2640:mm:ss….. indeed of the duration time.
I suspect there is an error in the calculation of the code, but I have no idea where to look.

Can someone help me?
I hanno no idea of Java programming.
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the Javascript interprets the supplied date as M/D/Y. Why don't you simply supply the parameter as the number of remaining seconds - which you can easily calculate in FM? Then it will work regardless of date format.

Comment: I recommend adding the `javascript` tag

Comment: Thanks  Michael.hor257k, unfortunately I have no idea how to program in Java….ca. You help me?

Comment: Solved withe the filemaker customer Function: date.format ( theDate ; format )

Answer (score 2):

Here is something very simple you could use as your starting point:

```
Let ([
seconds = Timer::Timestamp_End - Get(CurrentTimestamp) ;
html = "data:text/html, <html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
function count_down(seconds) {
i = seconds; 
h = Math.floor(i/3600);
m = Math.floor(i%3600/60);
s = i%60;
if (m < 10) { m = '0' + m };
if (s < 10) { s = '0' + s };
if (i > 0) { 
document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = h;
document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = m;
document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = s;
i--;
setTimeout('count_down(i)', 1000);
}
else {
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'Expired';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='count_down(«seconds»)'> 
<div id='timer'><span id='hr'></span>:<span id='min'></span>:<span id='sec'></span></div>
</body>
</html>" 
] ;
Substitute ( html ; "«seconds»" ; GetAsNumber ( seconds ) )
)
```

This assumes the `Timestamp_End` field is a Timestamp field.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make a new javascript, but it is too hard for me. Instead I have faced the previous one.....Just the last question:How I can fix the PLAY SOUND EFFECT? When the timer goes to 0, the background turned yellow [code]else if(secondsRemaining==0)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF00';
        document.getElementById('sound1').Play();[code], but I cannot hear any sound. I try to change audio file, path and audio type, but nothing worked. can you help me?

Comment: Are you asking about my code or yours?

Comment: Thanks michael, i’m asking about mine….I never study Java (actually I am a medical doctor), and I even if I try to use your code to make a new JavaScript I am unable to develo what I need for now…maybe this summer I will start learning also JavaScript, but now with pandemic I am out of time….